# confirm and prompt in user code for web workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm making a site that teaches beginners programming. They will write some code in an editor, click a button to run it, after which a web worker starts to run t heir code.

I have answered in [the comments for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23083918/147262) why I can't use `eval()`.

My question now is, I have defined functions that expose the `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()` dialogs, which works fine. However, the return values of the latter two are not returned to the web worker - even if I add `return`, I get   `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` Is it possible to modify the code to handle their return values?

Full code: http://pastebin.com/bnE128DE

Relevant parts are in the `runCode()` method:

```
var userCode = editor.getValue();
        // append functions and variables for drawing on Canvas
var codeWithMessages = '\n\
    function print  (data) { postMessage(["print", data.toString()]); } \n\
    function println(data) { postMessage(["print", data.toString() + "\\n"]); } \n\
    function alert  (data) { postMessage(["alert", data.toString()]); } \n\
    function confirm(data) { return postMessage(["confirm", data.toString()]); } \n\
    function prompt (data) { return postMessage(["prompt", data.toString()]); } \n\
    \n\
    ...
' + userCode;
        var codeWithMessagesAndExitValues = codeWithMessages + "..."

    // handle messages, calling window functions or exit and handle user return vars
    outer.worker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        var method = event.data[0] || null;
        var data   = event.data[1] || null;


        if (method == "canvas") {
            // call canvas methods
        } 
        else if(method == "exit") {
            // close the worker and  handle user variables
        } 
        else if(method == "alert") {
            alert(data);
        } 
        else if(method == "confirm") {
            confirm(data);
        }
        else if(method == "prompt") {
            prompt(data);
        } 
        else if(method == "print") {
            if ($("#run-output").text() == editorController.noOutputMsg)
                $("#run-output").text("");
            $("#run-output").append(data);
        }
```

Minimum example of user code:

```
print( prompt("Enter your name:") );
```

(entering anything will give the above error)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code into your question, instead of putting it somewhere else in the internet.

Comment: You cannot `return` synchronously from an async message anyway.

Comment: The relevant parts are in the `runCode()` method which is quite long. I have given it a shot in trying to break it down now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

That looks like you called the in-webworker `prompt`/`confirm` methods without a message, so that `data` was `undefined`. Not sure to say without the used code sample and the line number of the exception, though.

> the return values of the latter two are not returned to the web worker

Well, why would they? Not even your message event handler does attempt to do anything with their return values.

> Is it possible to modify the code to handle their return values?

No, since the worker-communication is asynchronous you never will be able to synchronous `return` values from a message.

Comment: I have updated the question with a minimal user code sample. I forgot to mention that I get the message even if I add return statements before the `postMessage` calls.

Comment: `prompt()` does return `postMessage()` does return `undefined` (because it's async, and because there is no "response" to a message), and that's what you're calling `print(undefined)` with, which throws the error that `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: I understood that, I just updated the question for the sake of completeness. If nobody else has anything to add, I will mark this question as answered after a few hours.